# Json in vue.js from swift contains nothing. Am I wrong in dealing with data?

Tags: arrays, json, swift, vuejs3, bridge

I need help to deal with a json data from swift iOS in a vuejs project.

A string type file contains in swift, so I send it using brigde, and it becomes an empty list in vuejs side.

Here is my codes:

```
// iOS
// Json data
var jsonString: String = ""

let encoder = JSONEncoder()
encoder.outputFormatting = .prettyPrinted
let jsonData = try encoder.encode(self.serverGlobalVariable.drvMyInfo)
if let enJsonString = String(data: jsonData, encoding: .utf8) {
print(enJsonString)
jsonString = enJsonString

// send payload by bridge


let script = "window.postMessage({command: 'set_myInfoList', payload: '\(jsonString)'});"

    // iOS to JS
    internal func sendMessageToVue(script: String) {
        print("function sendMessageToVue called")
        
        self.evaluateJavaScript(script) {result, error in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            } else if let result = result {
                print(result)
            } else {
                print("no return")
            }
        }
    }
```

```
<script type=ts setup>
// vuejs and typescript
// addListener
window.addEventListener(command.MESSAGE, handleBridgeMessage);

let myInfoList = ref([]);
var isSuccessful = ref<boolean>(false);

// bridge message
const handleBridgeMessage = (event) => {
  if (event.data.command === 'set_myInfoList') {
    console.log('set_myInfoList', event.data);  // cannot check on mobile
    isSuccessful.value = true;  // to display a tag on mobile => true checked

    try {
      // const templist = JSON.stringify(event.data.payloads);
      // const tempLust = JSON.parse(templist);
      const tempLust = JSON.parse(event.data.payload);
      myInfoList.value = tempLust;
    } catch (e) {
      console.error('Error parsing Json payload : ', e);
    };

    return
  }

};
```

So I tried to display a data in jsonString but the result is '[]'.
(i.g. {{ myInfoList }} or {{ myInfoList.name }} - there is data such as userId, name, etc.)

Please advice if there are any issues.

It was successful when I sent '1' or 'a', and I've tried to stringfy the json or to display without parsing.